# Short expression for "If you are not 100% convinced yet, this last thing will seal the deal"

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice, letter-writing

I'm writing a LinkedIn recommendation for a colleague of mine. I praised his abilities far and wide; now I would like to throw in one last (ironic and informal) punch line to top it all off.

Here is what I have so far:

> *You know how they say that if you want something done, you should ask the busiest person in the office to do it? This is the reason why
>   Andrea is my favorite go-to guy for all of my data digging and
>   reporting needs. Always working long hours, he still takes the time to
>   patiently listen to me and assist me with whatever problem I have and,
>   what’s more, he always does it with a smile. Quick, reliable and
>   helpful, Andrea is also – and by far – the most polite and
>   good-natured guy around. I am always at ease working with him.*

Now I want to add something like:

> *What seals the deal? He keeps a huge stash of candies in the first drawer of his desk, for everyone to take.*

Does that make any sense, or is the use of the expression "to seal the deal" inappropriate?
What other choices do I have?

Please feel free to add any comment (also regarding the first part of the letter) if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use "**The icing on the cake?** He keeps a huge stash of candies in the first drawer of his desk, for everyone to take."

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, I went with "the icing on the cake" in the end. @kristina lopez's suggestion was also very nice but I decided to keep it concise.

Comment: This rhymes too! :P

Answer (score 4):

Because it is a job recommendation, you might consider a little more formal way to introduce the candy story...

**To sum it up, I'd like to add this personal anecdote.  Andrea's generosity extends beyond his willingness to work long hours and help others.  He also keeps a drawer full of candy that he shares with the entire staff!  He's a *sweet* guy that will be a tremendous asset to your organization.**

Answer (score 2):

You have a good choice right in the text of your question:

> To top it all off. . .

*Edit to address OP's comment:*

Well, I don't know if this goes too far in the opposite direction, but it's strong on the face of it and cheekily ironic:

> But most importantly. . .

Comment: Thank you for your input John, I thought both about that and "the icing on the cake" as @curious_cat suggested, but I'm looking for something that "sounds stronger". It's not just a side note, it's not something I'm adding to a list of other equally important remarks, this has to be (ironically) the killer hit. 

Not sure I made sense :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to describe it as a *clincher* - that final detail that takes you over the edge of being undecided.

Comment: Nice! I almost like this better than my answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Pièce de résistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C3%A8ce_de_r%C3%A9sistance)? Maybe that would be kind of silly, but it's what came to my mind.